# First time using ESP8266, can't get it to connect to wifi

Tags: arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I'm trying to connect a Sensirion sps30 with a ESP8266 on wifi.
I used Arduino to program the ESP8266, but this is the first time I'm doing this.
I found a filled out sketch and I only had to put in the SSID and password.
I did that and the sensor now does a couple of measurements and then tries to connect to the wifi. After that it just tries to connect, but nothing happens.
I used a guide from GLOBE.nl for the set-up.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

I tried the Adafruit website and follow the steps, but nothing changed.
I've tried finding a YouTube video, but that didn't help either.

Comment: is your wifi is 2.4ghz mode only?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've contacted the IT-department at work and the problem lies most likely with the internet connection in building. I think that the coding is not the problem after all